# The subspace with sum of coefficients equals zero

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a real vector space and fix an Hamel basis $B\subseteq X$. In this way, every vector $x \in X$ has a unique representation $x=\sum_{b \in B} \lambda_{x,b}b$. Define now the vector subspace
$$
X_0:=\left\{x\in X: \sum_{b \in B}\lambda_{x,b}=0\right\}.
$$
Does $X_0$ have a "name" in relation with $X$?

Comment: Note that it depends very much on the choice of the basis.. If $B$ is finite, then any hyper-plane can do.

Comment: Surely, so a "good" notation could be $X_{0,B}$, anyway.. (I didn't add the index $B$ just because it was fixed, but it is clear that it depends on its choice.)